# Feed multiple integers from web page in to single javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a basic function to parse an API in json, and then a simple equation using the data I've parsed;

```
function UpdateStats(){
    $.getJSON("https://website-with-an-api.com/api/stats", function(data) {
        variable1 = parseInt(data.value);
        calc1 = parseInt(data.value2 / 100 * 86400);

        $("#value1 span").html((A VALUE 1 / variable1 * calc1).toFixed(0));
        $("#value2 span").html((A VALUE 2 / variable1 * calc1).toFixed(0));
        $("#value3 span").html((A VALUE 3 / variable1 * calc1).toFixed(0));

    });
}
```

I then have a corresponding web page, where the results are outputted

```
<p id='value1'><span></span></p>
<p id='value2'><span></span></p>
<p id='value3'><span></span></p>
```

Simple! But here's the thing. I will have potentially 1000's of calculations to do, in a large table (my input is shown as 'A VALUE X').

Rather than me specifying the individual calculations in my javascript file (and bloating it), how can I take a static value from my web page (let's say any value in column "H"), and then output the result for each row in a new a column or location?

So in other words, I obviously shouldn't be editing the my javascript file with new lines, each time I want to add a new row to my table; I should just be able to add a new row to my web page, and for the script to automatically detect the element and perform the calculation/output.

Comment: Can you show HTML from where you get `A VALUE X`?

Comment: Here's the actual page; https://www.uplexamining.com/hw-benchmarks/ - the column called 'H/s' is the source data, and the column called 'EST UPX /Day' is where I want the output. Right now, all of these are specified statically in the javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make some assumptions here (like that you are using jQuery)

But I would structure your HTML like this

```
<div class="row" id="value1"><span class="colA">10</span><span class="colB"></span></div>
<div class="row" id="value2"><span class="colA">15</span><span class="colB"></span></div>
<div class="row" id="value3"><span class="colA">20</span><span class="colB"></span></div>
<div class="row" id="value4"><span class="colA">25</span><span class="colB"></span></div>
```

and then the javascript where you loop each row (because selecting a class will give you an array of elements if there is more then 1)

```
<script>

    function UpdateStats(){
        $.getJSON("https://website-with-an-api.com/api/stats", function(data) {
            var variable1 = parseInt(data.value);
            var calc1 = parseInt(data.value2 / 100 * 86400);

            $('.row').each(function (el) {
                $el = $(el);
                var colBValue = (parseInt($el.find('.colA').text()) / variable1 ) * calc1;
                $el.find('.colB').html(colBValue).toFixed(0);
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

So for each row it will get the value for `colA` in that row and do some calculations, after that it will put the calculated value in `colB` in that row. `$el` refers to each row in the loop, `.find` will let you select elements within other elements

Comment: Wow, I've just performed a small test, and this seems to have done it! First answer through the door, thank you so much!